# selecting bricks from image

Tags: image-processing, matlab, image-segmentation

I have an image of bricks of different sizes. What I want to do is when I click on the corner of the brick it should mark the lines around the brick. Can anyone please help me how can I do that...
here is the image
[image]

Comment: I have tried using Sobel and canny edge but its not so sucessful

Comment: Please explain the reason before doing down vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest a simple solution , however if you want to go for a more robust solution let me know.

So first I would look for a way to enhance the signal. In my experience red objects appear even stronger if you look at red-green

```
diff = im(:,:,1) - im(:,:,2);
figure;imshow(diff,[]);
```

[image]

Than I would use simple thresholding (choose threshold value manually ) to get a blackwhite image.
To make it more robust I would use some morphology operations like opening and filling. (If you dont know what that is I would look at  [matlab help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/morphology-fundamentals-dilation-and-erosion.html#f18-24720).
Than finally you can select the brick with bwselect and take its perimeter with bwpeim.

Viola:

```
diff = im(:,:,1) - im(:,:,2) ;
bw = diff > 35;
bw = imopen( bw , ones(1,5) );
bw = imopen( bw , ones(5,1) );
bw = imfill(bw , 'holes');
brick = bwselect(bw);
brick = bwperim(brick);
```

and you can see a simple output here:
Please note that this is quite specific for this image but that's a good simple way to get you started.
[image]

Comment: Yes it helped me a lot to get close to what I expect. But I want to know that if I have 'x' and 'y' points of the brick than how can I select using bwselect?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to find the edges in this specific case. I order to select a brick you need to have some kind of representation such as, making whole brick'white or 1' and the gaps between two brick 'black/ 0'.

I processed the given image by first converting to RGB to BW and then adjust the contrast. After then I tried to  make the new image as I mentioned above by viewing the pixel values. example code is attached ;

I hope other people in this group may help you better than me.

BR
FF

[image: Image contrast]

Answer (score 0):

**Code for the above figure;**

```
for i=1:2112  % (image rows)
    for j=1:2816  % (image cols)
        if contrastAdjusted(i,j) < 110
            ff(i,j) = 1;
        else
            ff(i,j) = 0;
        end
    end
end
imshow(ff);
```

Comment: Please anyone can help me further